# How do things like Steam and the Blizzard Launcher create a GUI without using the default OS window?

Tags: c++, user-interface, msdn

When you open up Steam or something like the Blizzard Launcher, you'll notice quickly that they don't use the default Operating System window style. Their window frame, buttons, etc. are all custom and fancy.

I understand more or less how to create a window in C++ using the tools given by Microsoft (for Windows) or equivalent for other OSes, but I've not a clue how these fancy custom windows are created.

My brain is telling me that it must be some fancy trick using borderless windows, but that feels to much like a hack to me, something a big fancy tech company wouldn't have to cheat to pull off.

Thus I ask, assuming we're on Windows (just cuz bring in other OSes will complicate things), what exactly are these companies doing to achieve this fancy custom window affect? Is it some super low level thing a casual C++ hobbyist like me will never be able to do, or is it some fancy part of the windows tool set I can just look up on MSDN?

Comment: MS Windows has drawing messages for all the components of a window.  If you don't handle them you get the default look.  If you want to handle them you can change the look of your window.  eg `WM_NCPAINT`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-ncpaint   Also read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/user-controls-intro for controls

Comment: It's absolutely easy to create a custom window without borders or other usual decoration.  If you're using something like DirectX you may even be forced to do it that way.

Comment: OHHHHHH.... so it's a skin?

Comment: Or just host an HTML control in a window (frame or frame-less) and use HTML and CSS